# Return the difference between the lengths of the shortest and longest words (using for loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, string-length

I'm wondering how to return the difference between the lengths of the shortest and longest words (using a for loop):

```
function findShort(s){

 s = s.split(" ");

   (for let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
   ******code goes here******
}

}

findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps");
findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"); 
});
```

Any ideas? If someone would also like to try using something like map or reduce that would also be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for for loops. Just map the sentence into a list of word lengths, find the longest and shortest and subtract:

```js
function findShort(sentence) {
  const lengths = sentence.split(/\s+/).map(word => word.length);
  
  return Math.max(...lengths) - Math.min(...lengths);
}

console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
console.log(findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the array to a pair of `short` and `long` values, and return the delta:

```js
const findDelta = str => {
  const [long, short] = str.split(/\s+/)
    .reduce(([long, short], { length }) => [
      Math.max(long, length), // take the longest length
      Math.min(short, length) // take the shortest length
    ], [-Infinity, Infinity]) // init long with -Infinity and short with Infinity
    
  return long - short
}

console.log(findDelta("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"))
console.log(findDelta("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

- Map the array to the length of the words.
- Then sort the array it will look like `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]`
- Then build the difference between the longest and the shortest word.

Thats your result

```js
function findShort(s){

 s = s.split(" ");
 let leng = s.map((x) => {return x.length})
 leng.sort();
 return leng[leng.length-1] - leng[0];
}



console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
console.log(findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"));
```